# Magento 2 - url.build does not work for admin url

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax

I have tried `url.build` to build request url for **ajax call** in magento 2, it does not work ?

**JS File code:** ( view/adminhtml/web/js/files.js)

```
/*global window,requirejs*/
requirejs(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm', 'mage/url'], function ($, confirmation, urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';
    $('body #custom_email_button').on('click', function () {
        var requestUrl = urlBuilder.build('productpricequote/email/send');
        console.log(requestUrl);
    });
});
```

**Output:**

```
'productpricequote/email/send'
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please show us how you did, so that we can help.

Comment: and ouput of requestUrl also

Comment: Hello Mr.Kapil, Have you found the solution? If yes, do not forget to share in answer, with us.

Comment: same problem, you found a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found solution for this. we just need to add a / before url.

**Example:**

**JS File code:** ( view/adminhtml/web/js/files.js)

```
/*global requirejs*/
requirejs(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm', 'mage/url'], function ($, confirmation, urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';
    $('body #custom_email_button').on('click', function () {
        var requestUrl = urlBuilder.build('/productpricequote/email/send');
        console.log(requestUrl);
    });
});
```

**Output:**

```
'http://siteurl.com/productpricequote/email/send'
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The question was url.build does not work for admin url however the output of your answer is for frontend

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
define(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm', 'mage/url'], 
  function ($, confirmation, urlBuilder) {
   'use strict';

    $('body #custom_email_button').on('click', function () {
        var requestUrl = urlBuilder.build('productpricequote/email/send');
        console.log(requestUrl);
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the difference betn answer and question.

Comment: requirejs and define difference only, but still does not works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have implemented in your question is seemed to be accepted by all, but it does not work in fact. So I'm suggesting you some different way:

**1. Create a block** at app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/YourBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class YourBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $storeManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ) {
        $this->storeManager= $storeManager;
    }
    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

**2. In your template add this script:**

```
<script>
window.baseUrl = <?php echo json_encode($block->getBaseUrl()); ?>
</script>
```

**3. And update your script as follows:**

```
/*global window,requirejs*/
requirejs(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'], function ($, confirmation, urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';
    $('body #custom_email_button').on('click', function () {
        var requestUrl = window.baseUrl+'productpricequote/email/send'
        console.log(requestUrl);
    });
});
```

**4. Output**

```
YourBaseUrl/productpricequote/email/send
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this. But I want to generate url in js itself, i don't want to pass anything from phtml file.

Comment: Actually Kapil, I had wasted few days searching for the solutioin you are looking for, and ended up implementing this. So best of luck. If you are in rush you can use this way for now and look for your quest later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this use "/admin/productpricequote/email/send"

`urlBuilder.build("/admin/productpricequote/email/send");`

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's not a direct answer to the initial question but I hope it'll help someone.

In case you're looking for a way to pass a URL to a Knockout component that's configured in XML, you just need to use 'url' type instead of 'string'.

```
<item name="path" xsi:type="url" path="foo/bar/buzz"/>
```

And you'll get something like

```
https://yousitename.test/admin/foo/bar/buzz/key/59fc5267a61f37216f082211266f336ff7674b25153d2075efde9c3033fa872f/
```

An example of a button

```
<button name="sync" component="Module_Name/js/form/components/your_component_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }.sync</item>
                                <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">redirect</item>
                                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="path" xsi:type="url" path="foo/bar/buzz"/>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <title translate="true">Sync</title>

                    <imports>
                        <link name="customerId">${ $.provider }:data.customer_id</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </button>
```